# How to make swap on a removable SD card?

Tags: sd-card, swap

I have a 16GB SD card which shows as /dev/sdb unallocated space in Disks app. I can do

```
mkswap /dev/sdb
swapon /dev/sdb
```

but when I restart the whole thing disappears. How can I make it stay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to do this if you can avoid it, as it is slow and will cause the SD card to fail prematurely. That said

You need to mount the disk as swap in `/etc/fstab`. (i.e. edit that file with a text editor, and add the appropriate line with a filesystem type if swap. While you can specify `/dev/sdb` if this SD card is reliably registered as this at startup you might be better served using `blkid` to find the devices unique identifier and use that.

Comment: can you clarify why do you think the sd will fail? I used to have an older version of ubuntu on that laptop and the os designated the sd as a swap ( I think it was zswap ) and that gave me very good performance. The hd is much slower. my kids destroyed the setup by pulling the card and using it as a usb for regular files. I have been trying to re-create that initial setup. I upgraded to Lubuntu, but it did not choose the sd to be any kind of swap and the swap on the hd is 1gb with 4gb ram, so I cannot hibernate there.

Comment: Experience and reading up on the duty cycle of SD cards. Ae you sure you meant SD card and not SSD (but 16 gig ssd would be unusual)? Speed and reliability wise sd < hdd < ssd. You do get external SSD.

Comment: @K7AAY did you mean SD cards do not last... ?   As an order of magnitudes comparison I'd say SD cards are 30 meg/sec, HDD 100 meg/sec, SSD 500 meg/sec (ignoring latencies).  I think the condfounding factor here is ZSWAP which was not included in the original question and is designed to avoid disk reads/writes by compressing memory and delaying disk writes.

Comment: Yes, they don't last as long as well as are slower.

Comment: based on comments I will ask a new question: how to make zswap on the hdd. SD card will not be a good option for swap.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [zram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zram) instead. It's **much faster** than HDD, SD, eMMC or an older SSD (and possibly even many new SSDs based to the [benchmark results here](https://github.com/sergey-senozhatsky/zram-perf-test) with the default lzo algorithm) and causes **no wear on the flash memory**. You can change to [lzo-rle](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=ZRAM-Linux-5.1-Better-Perform) or [lz4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ4_(compression_algorithm)) (which is [nearly 5 times faster than lzo](https://github.com/lz4/lz4)) for even better performance with a little bit less compression ratio. In the future there may be [zstd support](https://askubuntu.com/q/1082710/253474) since it's been included in the latest Linux kernel. If you're low on RAM you can easily feel the difference system responsiveness after enabling it

Many modern OSes like [ChromeOS](https://web.archive.org/web/20130331021835/https://www.chromestory.com/2013/03/google-enabling-zram-for-chrome-os-by-default/), Android and various Linux distros ([Lubuntu](https://web.archive.org/web/20150819151859/http://linuxvillage.org/en/2013/10/next-lubuntu-provided-with-zram-enabled/), [Fedora](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Fedora-33-Aims-SWAP-On-ZRAM)) have **enabled zram by default** for years, especially for systems with less RAM. In fact [Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/319933/what-is-memory-compression-in-windows-10/) and [macOS](https://appleinsider.com/articles/13/06/12/compressed-memory-in-os-x-109-mavericks-aims-to-free-ram-extend-battery-life) also use similar [pagefile compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory_compression) techniques by default

You can make a small backup swap partition or swap file and keep it at a lower priority. If you're on Ubuntu just run `sudo apt-get install zram-config` and you're good to go. There's also [zswap](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/zswap) and [zcache](https://lwn.net/Articles/397574/). I haven't tried them but they're probably worth a try

## Further reading

- [Arch Linux - Improving performance - Zram or zswap](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/improving_performance#RAM_and_swap)
- [Enable ZSwap to increase performance](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/enable-zswap-to-increase-performance/11302)
- [Enable zRAM for improved memory handling and less swapping](https://portal.cloudunboxed.net/knowledgebase/35/Enable-zRAM-for-improved-memory-handling-and-less-swapping.html)
- [Running out of RAM in Ubuntu? Enable ZRAM](https://www.cnx-software.com/2018/05/14/running-out-of-ram-in-ubuntu-enable-zram/)
- [zram vs zswap vs zcache Ultimate guide: when to use which one](https://askubuntu.com/q/471912/253474)
- [Linux, SSD and swap](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/218078/44425)
- https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Zram